# How to change window title behaviour in LyX?

Tags: lyx

In LyX, the window title currently shows the complete path of the file. I want it to show only the file name. How can I do that?

LyX 2.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 Mate

Answer (score 4):

I do not think you can do this from within LyX. You might want to make a feature request on https://www.lyx.org/trac.

You might be able to hack something together outside of LyX based on your system's setup. For example, the following command finds a window with "LyX" in its name, and changes the name to "Hello":

```
xdotool search --name "LyX" set_window --name "Hello"
```

As for how to set this up to work automatically as you desire, you could modify the .desktop file for your lyx executable to fork a script that executes the xdotool command you would like after LyX starts up. However, this command would need to be run every time after LyX changes the window title (e.g. as it does when you open a different file). So I don't recommend trying to go this way.

Comment: Where would I find this .desktop file?

Comment: @UrYa'ar: `/usr/share/applications/lyx.desktop` (see https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/lyx/ for Arch and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lyx for Ubuntu).